# How to specify machine type in vertex ai pipeline

Tags: kubeflow, gcp-ai-platform-training, kubeflow-pipelines, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I want to specify the machine type in vertex ai pipeline with using kfp sdk.
I don't know how to specify machine_type while executing it as a component of pipeline.
I tried kfp.v2.google.experimental.run_as_aiplatform_custom_job, but it ran as CustomJobExecution instead of ContainerExecution.
For that reason, I want to use Airtifact, but airtifact is not mounted on this component.

Since I want to use the airtifact of the previous components and the function of Output [Airtifact], I want to execute it as ContainerExecution instead of CustomJobExecution.

Comment: Could you provide more overview details? Did you try to follow official `GCP` guide - [Configuring compute resources for custom training](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/configure-compute?hl=UK) ? Did you get any error?

Comment: @PjoterS, it looks like what you're proposing is for training jobs only. Do you know of a way to set the machine type for any pipeline component, while at the same time allowing the component to have access to the previous component outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use set_memory_limit and set_cpu_limit, just like you would using Kubeflow Pipelines. Vertex Pipelines will convert these limits to a machine type that satisfies your request.

Comment: Any idea how to do that when defining a TFX pipeline and running it with tfx.orchestration.experimental.KubeflowV2DagRunner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026549/specify-machine-type-for-a-single-tfx-pipeline-component-in-vertex-ai