# Specify machine type for a single TFX pipeline component in Vertex AI

Tags: tfx, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I'm using TFX to build an AI Pipeline on Vertex AI. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/gcp/vertex_pipelines_simple) to get started, then I adapted the pipeline to my own data which has over 100M rows of time series data. A couple of my components get killed midway because of memory issues, so I'd like to set the memory requirements for these components only. I use `KubeflowV2DagRunner` to orchestrated and launch the pipeline in Vertex AI with the following code:

```py
runner = tfx.orchestration.experimental.KubeflowV2DagRunner(
    config=tfx.orchestration.experimental.KubeflowV2DagRunnerConfig(
        default_image = 'gcr.io/watch-hop/hop-tfx-covid:0.6.2'
    ),
    output_filename=PIPELINE_DEFINITION_FILE)

_ = runner.run(
    create_pipeline(
        pipeline_name=PIPELINE_NAME,
        pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
        data_path=DATA_ROOT, metadata_path=METADATA_PATH))
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67816573/how-to-specify-machine-type-in-vertex-ai-pipeline) has been answered on Stack Overflow, which has led me to a way to [set memory requirements in AI Platform](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/cloud-ai-platform-pipelines#kubeflow_pipelines_resource_considerations), but these configs don't exist anymore in `KubeflowV2DagRunnerConfig`, so I'm at a dead end.

Any help would be much appreciated.

** EDIT **
We define our components as python functions with the `@component` decorator, so most of them are custom components. For Training components, I know you can specify the machine type using the `tfx.Trainer` class as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/gcp/vertex_pipelines_vertex_training#write_a_pipeline_definition), though my question is for custom components that are not doing any training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can't at the moment but according to this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/3194#issuecomment-802598448), this feature is coming.

An alternative solution is to convert your TFX pipeline to a Kubeflow pipeline. Vertex AI pipelines support kubeflow and with these you can set memory and cpu constraints at the component level.

```py
@component // imported from kfp.dsl
def MyComponent(Input[Dataset] input_data):
  // ...

@pipeline // imported from kfp.dsl
def MyPipeline(...):
  component = MyComponent(...)
  component.set_memory_limit('64G') // alternative to set_memory_request(...)
```

Comment: Oh dude, that cost me half a day today :( Apparently Vertex AI takes set_memory_limit and set_cpu_limit, but not _request counterparts.

It still behaves correctly in terms of providing a machine type with ram >= what's in set_memory_limit.

So, for a Vertex AI pipeline, correct code would be:

`component = MyComponent(...)
  component.set_memory_limit('64G')`

Comment: Thanks I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option to this solution would be using the dataflow beam runner which allows components to be run dataflow cluster via Vertex. I am still to find a way for specifying machine types for custom components

Sample beam input:

```
BIG_QUERY_WITH_DIRECT_RUNNER_BEAM_PIPELINE_ARGS = [
--project=  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT,
--temp_location= GCS_LOCAITON,
--runner=DataflowRunner
```

]

By now you would be migrating to Vertex AI